# RC4 encryption cpp algorithm

Tags: c++, encryption

I am writing a program that can encrypt files using the cipher RC4,
In my file "test.txt" is a word "Plaintext",
the program should encrypt and save it also in a file (for test I was using "cout")

I thing there is a problem with the last part of the code

```cpp
while ( plik.read(&x,1) )
{
  i = ( i + 1 ) % 256;
  j = ( j + S [ i ] ) % 256;
  swap( S [ i ], S [ j ] );
  temp = S [ ( S [ i ] + S [ j ] ) % 256 ] ^ x;
  cout << temp;
}
```

There is no errors and no warnings,
What should I change?

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
 
 unsigned char S[256];

 int i = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
   S [ i ] = i;

 string Key;
 cout << "Enter the key: ";
 cin >> Key;

int j = 0;
 for ( i = 0; i < 256; i++ )
 {
   j = ( j + S [ i ] + Key.at( i % Key.length() ) ) % 256;
   swap( S [ i ], S [ j ] );
 }

 ifstream plik; 
 string path = "tekst.txt";
 plik.open( path );
 char tekst;
 plik >> tekst;

 string printFile = "Encryption_" + path;
 ofstream outfile( printFile );
 
 char x;
 j = 0;
 i = 0;
 string temp;
 while ( plik.read(&x,1) )
 {
   i = ( i + 1 ) % 256;
   j = ( j + S [ i ] ) % 256;
   swap( S [ i ], S [ j ] );
   temp = S [ ( S [ i ] + S [ j ] ) % 256 ] ^ x;
   cout << temp;
 }
 
 plik.close();
 outfile.close();
 
 return 0;
}
```

My key is: "key" and the result should be

[Good Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFdMb.png)

[image: My bad result]

Comment: yes, I am writing the result in console (only for testing, I will change that at the end), I have edited a post and you can see my result

Comment: Pay attention to upper/lower case for plaintext and key. The ciphertext you posted results for `Plaintext` and `Key` (not `key`), s. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=RC4(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'Key'%7D,'Latin1','Hex')&input=UGxhaW50ZXh0). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61167845/9014097) you can find an RC4 implementation in C/C++ that works. Maybe you can identify the issue by comparing the logics.

Comment: You can find reference test examples [here in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Test_vectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is mathematically totally correct, I just did few small corrections to other parts of your code and your code made correct output.

For testing purposes lets take test examples [here from Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Test_vectors), first example. Input key will be `Key`, input file will be `Plaintext`, resulting file should be `BB F3 16 E8 D9 40 AF 0A D3` in hex. Following modified code passes this test.

In code below you input a key from console, then input file is taken from `tekst.txt` and output file is written to `Encryption_tekst.txt`. It is better not to print result to console as ASCII chars but to view resulting file in hex viewer, because console will mess up with character encodings, better to view in hex.

I added printing to console of resulting hex characters. Also **notice** that in following code very first block writes `Plaintext` to `tekst.txt`, I did this for the purpose of example, so that code can be just copy pasted and run without any extra dependencies. You have to delete very first block that writes to `teks.txt`, because you have your own input `tekst.txt` and it will be overwritten.

When you run following example enter `Key` in console prompt.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/7zhMT5jrK)

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    {
        ofstream out("tekst.txt");
        out << "Plaintext";
    }

    unsigned char S[256];

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        S[i] = i;

    string Key;
    cout << "Enter the key: ";
    cin >> Key;

    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        j = (j + S[i] + Key.at(i % Key.length())) % 256;
        swap(S[i], S[j]);
    }

    ifstream plik;
    string path = "tekst.txt";
    plik.open(path);

    string printFile = "Encryption_" + path;
    ofstream outfile(printFile);

    char x;
    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    char temp = 0;
    while (plik.read(&x, 1)) {
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + S[i]) % 256;
        swap(S[i], S[j]);
        temp = S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256] ^ x;
        outfile << temp;
        cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
             << uint32_t(uint8_t(temp)) << " ";
    }

    plik.close();
    outfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Input key (from console):

```
Key
```

Input file `tekst.txt`:

```
Plaintext
```

Console output:

```
Enter the key: Key
bb f3 16 e8 d9 40 af 0a d3
```

Output `Encryption_tekst.txt` viewed in hex viewer with code page `CP1252`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @Arty, I have added your corrections and it works perfectly

Comment: @Wujas Thanks for Accepting and UpVoting :) You had a very interesting question. For the first time I had a chance to study this RC4 algorithm to understand how it works. Very simple algorithm, maybe quite weak but simple to implement.